# adding 1 to the previous row based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

```
data=[['A',1,30],
      ['A',1,2],
      ['A',0,4],
      ['A',1,4],
      ['B',0,5],
      ['B',1,1],
      ['B',0,5],
      ['B',1,8]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['group','var_1','var_2'])
```

I want to create a series of values with index based on below condition:

Step 1) Increment should always happen from 1st row of 'var_2'of each group. For example: for group A, the increment should start from 30 and for group B, 
increment should start from 5
Step 2) Incremented value where 'var_1" = 1

My desired output:

```
0    30
1    31
3    32
5    6
7    7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
#Get first index in each group and union index where var_1 ==1
indx = df.drop_duplicates('group').index.union(df[(df['var_1']==1)].index)

#Reindex dataframe group by group, add cusum value to other present values in group.   
#Use .loc to filter where var_1 != 0 and get column var_2
df.reindex(indx).groupby('group')\
  .transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0] + x.shift().notna().cumsum())\
  .loc[lambda x: x.var_1 !=0, 'var_2']
```

Output:

```
0    30
1    31
3    32
5     6
7     7
Name: var_2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try groupby `cumcount` and `first`

```
df1 = df.loc[df.var_1.eq(1)]
g = df1.groupby('group')['var_2']

g.transform('first') + g.cumcount()

Out[66]:
0    30
1    31
3    32
5     1
7     2
dtype: int64
```

---

Or use `duplicated` with `df.where` and `cumsum`

```
df1 = df.loc[df.var_1.eq(1)]
df1.var_2.where(~df1.duplicated('group'), 1).groupby(df1.group).cumsum()

Out[77]:
0    30
1    31
3    32
5     1
7     2
Name: var_2, dtype: int64
```